# How to dynamically update client in rails when data in database changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like the data on a page to update as soon as it changes in database.
Is there a way I can trigger some event on server when data changes and send it to the client?

For example a user might see the number of friend requests he has and that number should update in realtime if some other user adds that user as a friend.

Answer (score 5):

This is a brand new feature in Rails 4 (Server sent events). There is a [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/401-actioncontroller-live) on this topic.

Comment: I don't think the mechanics of sending the events to the client are the main problem here. Where those events come from is the challenging bit.

Answer (score 1):

If i m not wrong, then you are trying to write a Rails application in which a server can push data to multiple clients in real time.
Their are many guides that involve real-time push, and Rails 3.

- Juggernaut

You can try juggernaut to do what you want.
The github repository : https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut Example of application with juggernaut : https://github.com/maccman/holla

- Faye

Check out Faye: http://faye.jcoglan.com/ - I hear really good things about it.
if you're looking for a hosted solution, i've used Pusher http://pusher.com/ in the past, and loved it. i converted a site that used ajax polling over to pusher in about 30 minutes.

- Ajax Push Engine - Complete Comet solution

You could use [APE (Ajax Push Engine) Rails plugin](https://github.com/yalcin/APE-on-Rails).
APE is a full-featured OpenSource solution designed for Ajax Push. It includes a comet server and a Javascript Framework. APE allows to implement any kind of real-time data streaming to a web browser, without having to install anything on the client-side.

I hope this helps you.

Thanks

Comment: juggernaut seems to be deprecated.